# the set of all homeomorphisms of a space $(X, T)$ onto itself is a subgroup of the permutation group of $X$

Tags: general-topology

Prove that the set of all homeomorphisms of a space $(X, T)$ onto itself 
is a subgroup of the permutation group of $X$

---

Can someone help me to solve this problem please?

Comment: Suppose that $G$ is any group, and $H$ is a subSET of $G$. What must you prove in order to show that $H$ is a subGROUP of $G$? You must be able to answer that in order to get started on your problem, and if you **can** answer it, your problem becomes very straightforward.

Comment: $ab^{-1} \in H$.but how can I apply it here?and also to the permutation group.

Comment: Make sure that you know the definition of *every* term that you’ve used.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: Let $\mathscr{H}$ be the set of homeomorphisms of $X$ onto itself. You know that it suffices to show that if $g,h\in\mathscr{H}$, then $g\circ h^{-1}\in\mathscr{H}$ as well.

- If $h$ is a homeomorphism, is $h^{-1}$ a homeomorphism?
- Is the composition of two homeomorphisms a homeomorphism?

You should know the answers to both of these questions, but even if you don’t, the answers are very easy to discover and prove.